# Is there a way to build scss files into css with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack-4

I'm just trying out Webpack 4 and I was wondering if it had a built-in way to manage Scss files since ExtractTextPlugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Webpack 4* you also need to use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` in order to extract text from bundles. The problem is that stable version isn't compatible with the new plugin system. The team is working on it, but in the meantime you need to install the [v4.0.0-beta.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0) version.

```
yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin@next --dev
```

You can also check this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) on GitHub with more configs.

The use on `webpack.config.js` script remains the same:

---

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: true,
                                camelCase: 'dashes',
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css')
    ]
}
```

Comment: so i had something similar and i copied/pasted yours and i still am not getting any css files to be created.

Comment: in my [webpack-demo project](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) I have the previous configuration working. did you check it?

Comment: yeah i figured it out. thanks. I have to include it in the entry point before it evaluates it.